# WCF with Castle Windsor error handling to Application Insights

Tags: c#, wcf, error-handling, castle-windsor, azure-application-insights

I have the following scenario:

- I am using castle windsor component activator to create and destroy the scope for the WCF.

I have a WCFServiceActivator that extends Castles DefaultcomponentActivator and implements the InternalCreate and InternalDestroy to call BeginScope and Scope.Dispose() for the service.

- WCF session is defined as per request
- I implemented a ErrorHandler class and defined the ProvideFault and HandleError
- In the handle error I want to send exception metrics to ApplicationInsights, but when I use castle to provide some factory I get no scope, since it was already destroyed after the provide value runs and the response is sent to the client.

Basically when the HandleError method executes, the scope created by the activator was already destroyed due to the perWcfRequestLifecycle.

I was wondering on maybe creating a new Castle LifecycleStyle that wraps a higher layer of the wcf but I don't know if it is possible.

Does someone have a solution for this scope issue?

Comment: Can you provide more details? I am not sure if the information you provide is enough to understand the problem.

Comment: Can you please recheck @YacoubMassad, thanks

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the ErrorHandler is created once in the application and not per wcf call. This would mean that it is not possible to "wrap a higher layer" since these layers don't have the lifetime of the call, which you require.